# Where to find Yuri Manin's “Lectures on zeta functions and motives”

Tags: reference-request

It seems a vary excellent note on motives. But I cannot find it on the internet. Could someone tell me where to find it. Thanks.

BTW, is this note a first course in motives? I know Yves André's book is a good reference, but I don't know French.

Comment: http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preblob/4793

Comment: Thanks vary much. The link is in nLab, and I missed it.